# Is Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, azure-table-storage

We are querying Azure storage tables via `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient` from multiple threads. Is it already thread-safe or do we have to make it so? (The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet) neither mentions threads nor concurrency.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, TableClient is thread safe.

More on that topic is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/thread-safety)

Comment: In addition, you can find a section in the readme about thread safety here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables#thread-safety